# OS X Lion: AppleScript unbearably slow for moving Mail messages

Tags: macos, osx-lion, applescript

I've been using for years now the following applescript, triggered via [iKey](http://plumamazing.com/mac/ikey) by an `F12` keystroke:

```
tell application "Mail" to move (get selection) to mailbox "Archive"
```

I'm using it to move inbox messages to the archive, which makes for efficient filtering by backspace/F12 keystrokes.

On 10.5 and 10.6 it would work nearly instantly, but with 10.7 there is a 1-3 seconds delay until the message disappears from the inbox, and during that time the rest of the interface is non-responsive (can't click other messages).

I'm pretty sure it's not a fault of iKey since other macros triggered through it in Mail.app (such as typing some text) work instantly as before.

How should I approach solving this?

Comment: A similar thread was posted at [MacScripter / Mail.app "move message" command ridiculously slow in Lion](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=36713). There's no answers at the moment.

Comment: I'm the OP of the MacScripter thread. Would love to hear if anyone comes up with a resolution. I've submitted a bug report to Apple (Open Radar [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1287403)). Feel free to do the same!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find an indirect solution to my specific problem, by using Mail's Archive command (under the Message menu).

I'm just using iKey's to trigger this menu command instead of any AppleScript, but I guess you could also easily use pure AppleScript for triggering this menu item (or moving to some other mailbox via the Move To submenu...)